# Changing JAVA DNS Cache settings

Tags: java, caching, dns

I am using java8 for my web application. I would like to change the settings of JAVA DNS Cache.
This is the code:

```
java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "60");
java.security.Security.setProperty("sun.net.inetaddr.negative.ttl", "10");
```

I would like to know where exactly I should write the code (in which class file) to reflect the changes in JVM before DNS chance gets initialised.

I would like to make the change using a  java utility class file.Please suggest for the same. 
And also suggest how to configure the same change in build.xml(ant)?

I agree with answers updated where they have suggested to change security file.But i would like to know the configuration in other ways too due to limitations that i have in my project.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set it globally by add this line

`networkaddress.cache.ttl=60`

to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` file.

Comment: I would like to make the change from java class file or any xml file.Please suggest for both

Comment: where should I set it ?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to set it directly in the java.security file located in /lib/security

Note: if you are using a shared JVM, you'll need to set this in your startup command `-Djava.security.properties=/DirectoryPath/filename` and set the value of `security.overridePropertiesFile` to true.

Comment: would like to make the change from java class file or any xml file.Please suggest for both.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set this in code then you have a number of options - you just need to put the code in a place that you know will be executed before the first message is processed after application startup.

My preference would be to register a [ContextListener](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/) and put the code in there.

Comment: I will create a class and keep these two lines of code in a static block(will be initialised when class file loads). And configure the class such that it will load when the server loads the war file. Is that sufficient?

Comment: You can do that, but I think it makes your life more difficult. How will you ensure the class is loaded? The ContextListener approach guarantees that the code will be executed without you having to think too much about the order that classes will be loaded

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue where my java application wouldn't resolve the URL.
In addition to what is suggested ( i.e.,networkaddress.cache.ttl and networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl) I had to reset the caches in the URL Object.

```
URL url = new URL(urlSrt);
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.setUseCaches(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of (build.xml)ant. I will still give it a try just in case you are using spring framework. Following is what I did to set the `networkaddress.cache.ttl` at the time of application initialisation.

1. Define a new Java class as follows.

   ```
   package com.example.util;
   public class SecurityManager {
     public SecurityManager() {
       java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "60");
     }
   }
   ```
2. Ask spring framework to instantiate the object of above class as a singleton at the time on spring container creation.

   ```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

     <bean id="securityManager" 
       class="com.example.util.SecurityManager" scope="singleton" />

   </beans>
   ```